# unity3d apps crash unexpectedly on Cyanogenmod 7.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, crashes

I have a Huawei u8160 which is running Cyanogenmod 7.2.

So all of the unity3d apps crash unexpectedly on start .

And I think that the error is because of missing kernels or libraries.

And I want to know if I can install any of them so I can run these apps.